# Does s3 upload using boto3 take care of verifying file upload and what happens in case of partial upload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using boto3 for uploading files into s3 buckets using `boto3.client. upload_file()`.

I had the following questions regarding this:

1. How does it handle the case where upload fails mid way due to network (does it upload only partial data or does it dosen't upload anything)?
2. Also does this function call verify the integrity of the file and check for data corruption or do I need to handle this case separately?